# cocos2d help: CCMenuItem unselected 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS' and CCCallFunc

Tags: memory-management, cocos2d-iphone, selector, exc-bad-access, ccaction

I've been having problems with CCMenuItem and its timing with CCCallFunc.

Basically I'm getting 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS'

@ this line of the CCMenuItem class

```
-(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    ...
    [selectedItem_ unselected]; // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    [selectedItem_ activate];
    ...
}
```

It seems the menu item is deallocated before the touch ends. I'm using CCCallFunc to call a 'removeThisSprite' method that removes it from the parent

so the last action of the CCMenuItem sequence I call:

```
[CCCallFuncO actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(removeThisSprite:) object: _currentButton]
```

The removeThisSprite method is like this:

```
CCMenuItemSprite2 *sender = nil;
sender.isEnabled = NO;

if ([_sender isKindOfClass:[CCMenuItemSprite class]]) {
    sender = _sender;
    [sender removeFromParentAndCleanup: YES];
}
```

This generally happens when the player 'spams' the screen with taps, but doesn't happen unless the taps are rapid. Which is likely to occur with a game I'm making. I'm guessing there's some sort of timing issue going on with players pressing the button too fast.

Answer (score 2):

You can always try and delay the removal of the menu item:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(removeMenuItem:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.1f];

...

-(void) removeMenuItem:(id)sender
{
   if ([sender isKindOfClass:[CCMenuItemSprite class]])
   {
      [sender removeFromParentAndCleanup: YES];
   }
}
```